# PrimeNg is adding empty chip along with the typed string when enter key is pressed

Tags: angular, primeng

My code is as follows, this is just a bunch of code for experimental purposes. I entered a value with no spaces before, after or between the text but I got "two chips"

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'imoveis';
   nome:Array<pessoa>  = new Array<pessoa>();
   basic:string = "d";
  
   ngOnInit(){
     let p:pessoa = new pessoa();
     this.nome.push(p);
   }

   adicionar(event:any):void{

    let p:pessoa = new pessoa();
    p.nome = event.value;
    this.nome.push(p);
    
 
 }

}



class pessoa{
   nome:string = "diego"; 
}
```

template

```
<p-chips (onAdd)="adicionar($event)" [disabled]="false" [max]="2"  [(ngModel)]="nome">
    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item" >
        {{  item.nome }}
    </ng-template>



  </p-chips>
```

[image: erro no layout imagem]

Answer (score 0):

Because after you have initialized with `diego` and you add `CARLOS`, `nome` looks like this.

```json
[
    {
        "nome": "diego"
    },
    "CARLOS",
    {
        "nome": "CARLOS"
    }
]
```

Template tries to read `{{ item.nome }}` but `"CARLOS"` is not an object with property `nome`, it's just a string. But prime-ng chips still sees that something should be there, so it adds a nameless chip. Problem originates form `onAdd` and `ngModel`, they both will add a value to `nome[]`. `ngModel` adds the string and `onAdd` adds obj typeof person.

PrimeNG chips is meant to hold array of strings, not objects.

```js
nome: string[] = ['diego', 'CARLOS']
```

Refactored:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  nome: string[] = ['diego'];
}
```

```html
<p-chips [disabled]="false" [max]="2" [(ngModel)]="nome">
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    {{ item }}
  </ng-template>
</p-chips>
```

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-chips-demo-hsbneu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html